# CSS Image doesnt fit the screen

Tags: html, css, background, screen

I am having trouble here. I got a background image that is 1024x960, and I want it to fit in all type of resolutions, but impressively, it is overextending a bit on all screens.

This is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../testes/jogo.bmp");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

I guess there has to be a mistake with the code, but yet every time I read it I feel it's ok but obviously it's not.

Comment: Instead of `background-image`set only `background` - background: transparent url(../testes/jogo.bmp) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;

Comment: just did, it shows me the same result.

Comment: It's already working check http://jsfiddle.net/f29ubL9o/

Comment: what is the expected output, it seems its working fine

Comment: This is going to be a javascript game, and I want this to fit all type of screen resolutions.
Could this be because of my 1366x768 resolution? But yet, the image should fit in all screens...

this is what I can see: http://i.imgur.com/3ALNCCt.png

Comment: On the body, set `margin:0:` and `padding:0;`

Comment: What is the expected output? `contain` and `cover` fit the image proportionally, `cover` makes the image overflow horizontally (or vertically) while `contain` adds gap horizontally (or vertically).

Comment: your code works as it should be. With "cover" the image will always fill the container (in this case your body) without any deform- This means that always it will "overextend" vertically or horizontally (never both) depending of the resolution of your image. If you use "contain" that image will never "overextend" but it will leave vertical or horizontal space.

Comment: I guess contain does the job, although it doesnt fit the screen horizontally, its still a prettiest result than cover.

Thanks a bunch for all help!

Comment: @JoãoMarques I've explained the 1366x768 issue in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
body { 
  background: url('../images/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Frorm the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp):

> Cover: Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

If you want the image to be fully in view, you can use

```
background-size:contain;
```

> Contain: Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background-image: url("../testes/jogo.bmp")  no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
}
```

[you can see here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score -1):

Try This Code:

```css
body {
background-image: url("http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Natural-dam.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```